# Installing python-pip3 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, pip

Installing python3-pip in ubuntu 20.04 via apt from the official ubuntu repos we are having some strange behaviour because pip3 is installed in */user/local/bin/pip3* instead */user/bin/pip3*.

is not a a standard installation because we joined a Domain via an Active Directory (AD) Bridging which enables non-Windows systems to be joined to AD and add some restriction via PAM and we run some hardening but we started to have this issue with ubuntu 20.04.

what may have been changed which cause pip3 to install to /usr/local/bin at first i thought was a different behaviour from ubuntu 18.04 but testing the same installation with no Domain and no Hardening pip3 is installed on /user/bin/pip3 so we did something but what can be happened? what could have influenced apt to install the package in */usr/local/bin*?

Comment: What does `apt-file list python3-pip | grep pip3` return? What about `apt policy python3-pip`? Please add to your question.

Comment: i will put the result of the command tomorrow

Comment: One more question: did you happen to run any **pip3** commands with sudo?

Answer (score 3):

**apt is almost certainly not putting files in /usr/local/bin**

Apt does not install pip to `/usr/local/bin`. Generally apt does not chose where files go at all. It just unpacks tar files (like zip files) that define the place files go.

So if apt was going to place pip in /usr/local/bin then the package (dpkg file) would contain a file named usr/local/bin/pip3.  We can prove that's not the case...

According to [this page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/all/python3-pip/download) `python3-pip` is currently available from security.ubuntu.com.  When I follow that trail and read the contents file [here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/) the files are all strictly in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/bin` etc, not `/usr/local/bin/...`

one thing that will install to `/usr/local/` by default is pip itself.  It's quite likely someone on your system has executed something like this as root:

```bash
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Or

```bash
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

This should not delete the version installed by apt, but will install a new version into `/usr/local/bin/`